# XAML parse exception - can find attached property in the debug version of the app, but not in release/installed version

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controls, attached-properties

I got an attached property like:

```cs
namespace Project.Controls.MyControl
{
    public static class Transform
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty RelativeOffsetXProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "RelativeOffsetX",
            typeof(double),
            typeof(Transform),
            new PropertyMetadata(
                default(double),
                OnRelativeOffsetXChanged));

        // ...
    }
}
```

which is used like:

```cs
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Project.Controls.MyControl">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControl}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Controls/MyControl/IndexItemStyle.xaml" />
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Controls/MyControl/ArrowButtonStyle.xaml" />
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Controls/MyControl/MyControlTemplate.xaml" />
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </Style.Resources>
        
        <!--  more code -->

        <Setter Property="IncreaseInAnimation">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Storyboard>
                    <!-- more code -->
                    <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0"
                                     FillBehavior="HoldEnd"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(local:Transform.RelativeOffsetX)"
                                     From="1"
                                     To="0"
                                     Duration="0:0:0.3" />
                </Storyboard>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

This works great in debug no issues. But when installing the production version of the app, it crashes at startup with the following exception:

> Type reference cannot find type named '{clr-namespace:Project.Controls.MyControl;assembly=Project, Version=X.X.X.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXX}Transform'

Does anyone have any idea what causes this or some tips on how to debug it? This error makes absolutely no sense, especially that everything works just fine in debug.

**NOTE:** Everything is in the same assembly.

Comment: You mean `public Project.Controls.MyControl` should actually be `namespace Project.Controls.MyControl`, and there is also a class named `MyControl` in that namespace with a property named `IncreaseInAnimation` of type Storyboard?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean good catch. I can't really copy paste code from the project so that was a mistake on my part. I fixed it now. There is a `MyControl` class in the `Project.Controls.MyControl` namespace which has the said property.

Comment: Sounds totally odd. The control has a Storyboard property to which you assign a Storyboard with a DoubleAnimation that is supposed to animate the attached property on the same control instance? Why should the Storyboard be stored by a control property?

Comment: It's not my code, it's based on this project https://github.com/GuOrg/Gu.Wpf.FlipView. I had to take parts and modify it for my needs, but that's beside the point. The code works as expected when launching the debug. For some reason the type reference fails in the prod version.

Comment: Or you had just build something strange that works in a Debug version by accident, who knows.

Comment: Again, it's not something I built. Also, I don't really believe it accidentally works in the dev version, because it works perfectly. I just think that perhaps our install shield creation process omits the class for some reason or something else is wrong with my XAML. The animation logic should be good or at least proven to work as expected

Comment: Try to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: My hope with this post is that someone would stop something obviously wrong with this (_e.g._ wrong namespace format) or has gone through something similar. Providing a minimum reproductible exmaple when this is not really reproducible unless it's the InstallShield version of some complex app is not really something I can do

Comment: @vladek: So how exactly are you "installing the production version of the app"?

Comment: I just found out what the issue is (but not sure how to solve it yet). When I open the installed exe with ILSpy the static class `Project.Controls.MyControl.Transform` is _missing_. When I open the exe in the debug folder, it's _not_ missing. I don't know why this is, maybe optimized away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this issue has nothing to do with WPF. The obfuscator we use simply optimized this class out. The solution was to exclude this file from obfuscation.